# Apache > mod_auth_dbm combine group and user files

Tags: apache-2.2, git

I have created a Git server with `git-http-backend` on a VPS with CentOS 6.5, and use `htpasswd` authentication. The relevant section used to look like this:

```
  <LocationMatch ".*">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Repositories"
    AuthUserFile /etc/gitdata/gitusers.passwd
    Require valid-user
  </LocationMatch>
```

The drawback of this is that all valid users would get access to all repositories. Now, I would like users or groups of users to have access to specific repositories only. Research shows that this is best accomplished with Apache's `mod_auth_dbm`. So, I created a setup like this:

```
  ServerName git.myserver.com

  ScriptAlias / /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
  DocumentRoot "/var/git"

  SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/git
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
  SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER


 <Directory "/">
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Includes +ExecCGI

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Repositories"
    AuthDBMGroupFile /etc/gitdata/userbase
    AuthDBMUserFile /etc/gitdata/userbase
    Require group admin
  </Directory>

 <Directory "/projects">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny

    AuthName "Project Repository - projects"
    AuthType Basic
    Require group admin

    <Limit GET PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
      Require group admin
    </Limit>
  </Directory>
```

I then created the `userbase` file using `htdbm`, and created a user in it like this:

```
sudo htdbm -bt /etc/gitdata/userbase xedinunknown "mysecretpassword" "admin:Main Admin"
```

So now, my `userbase` file looks like this:

```
$ sudo htdbm -l /etc/gitdata/userbase
Dumping records from database -- /etc/gitdata/userbase
    Username                         Comment
    xedinunknown                     admin:Main Admin
Total #records : 1
```

Some examples, as well as the [mod_auth_dbm documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_dbm.html), have lead me to believe that in this case, `admin` would be the group to which the user `xedinunknown` belongs. However, trying to clone the repository gives me an authentication error:

```
git clone http://xedinunknown@git.myserver.com/projects
Cloning into 'projects'...
Password for 'http://xedinunknown@git.myserver.com': 
fatal: Authentication failed
```

I must mention that documentation for the module specifies that it is possible to combine the group and user files, but nowhere does it say how. Have I missed something? Has anyone here done this before? If so, please explain.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

```
$ sudo httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 13 2013 17:29:28

$ sudo httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 ldap_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 usertrack_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 disk_cache_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Anybody? Any ideas? Perhaps, it is the wrong place to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

The way this looks, `admin` is probably treated as part of the comment and not as a group. According to documentation, you should use `dbmmanage` to assign groups to users. Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/dbmmanage.html .

Comment: `-bash: dbmmanage: command not found`. Weird...